# Pandas searching for list in Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe with lots of columns and one of them is a list of IDs.

e.g.

```
   |  IDs        |  IPs     |  ...
 1 |[12, 55, 15] |  123...  |  ...
 2 |[12]         |  222...  |  ...
 3 |[10, 11, 5]  |  234...  |  ...  
 4 |[12, 55, 15] |  123...  |  ...
 5 |[12, 55, 15] |  123...  |  ...
```

I have another list

```
l1 = [12 , 15, 55]
```

The results I want

```
   |  IDs        |  IPs     |  ...
 1 |[12, 55, 15] |  123...  |  ...
 4 |[12, 55, 15] |  123...  |  ...
 5 |[12, 55, 15] |  123...  |  ...
```

I have tried using `.isin`, `.query`, and tried to other solutions online but none of them worked for me. The result I gotten are empty dataframes and

```
0          False
1          False
2          False
3          False
4          False
```

edit:
The order is not important. I just want the numbers in the list to be in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `tuple`s if order is important:

```
import ast

#if necessary convert strings to lists
df['IDs'] = df['IDs'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

mask = df['IDs'].apply(tuple).eq(tuple(l1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply lambda` if order is important.

```
df.IDs.apply(lambda x: x == l1)
```

Comment: I've tried this too but it doesn't match... The list is in the dataframe as I've check using Excel. 




0          False
3622435    False

Answer (score 0):

This a solution I have found :

Edit : Actually really close solution from Hamza usman ghani's one. What is wrong exactly with his ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"column":[[12, 55, 15],[12, 55, 15],[12],[12, 55, 15]],"value":[5,5,1,5]})
print(df["column"].apply(lambda x : x==[12,55,15])) # prints {0,True ... }
print(df[df["column"].apply(lambda x : x==[12,55,15])]) # prints what you want
```

Comment: So if not working then not working all answers (also my answer too).

Comment: Yes I realized that after. I am still waiting for more informations about what is wrong.